# Отсортировать массив, сохраняя номера индексов ячеек массива

Tags: c++, qt

пять входных данных:
11 40 35 15 25

после сортировки будет:
11 15 25 35 40
no номер индекса:
1 4 5 3 2

Как можно это сделать в qt4.7.8?

---

Есть у меня структура с данными

```
   struct Bal{
   unsigned short int Voltage;
   unsigned short int index;
   };
   Bal massifVoltageAndIndex[247];
```

Есть функция сортировки

```
template< class T >
void bubbleSort(T* arr, int size)
{
T tmp;

for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i) // i - номер прохода
{
    for(int j = 0; j < size - 1; ++j) // внутренний цикл прохода
    {
        if (arr[j + 1] < arr[j])
        {
            tmp = arr[j + 1];
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = tmp;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Хочу отсортировать по параметру  Voltage. Остальные параметры сохранить. 
Что для этого нужно сделать?

Comment: Ввести параллельный массив с индексами или объединить данные в структуры с индексами?

Comment: Можно пример со структурой?

Comment: Я добавил информацию в свой ответ о том, как сделать так, чтобы функция `bubbleSort`  заработала.

Comment: Дайте знать, помогло ли вам моё решение, которое я добавил?

Answer (score 6):

Ещё один вариант решения, с `std::map`:

Используем `std::transform` и `std::inserter` для копирования вводных данных в map, где они автоматически сортируются.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> input = {11, 40, 35, 15, 25};

    unsigned index = 0;

    std::map<int, unsigned> lut;

    std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), std::inserter(lut, lut.begin()), [&](const int i)
    {
        return std::make_pair(i, ++index);
    });

    for(const auto & p : lut)
    {
        std::cout << p.first << " " << p.second << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Вывод:

```
11 1
15 4
25 5
35 3
40 2
```

Вот этот код выполняет копирование вводных данных в map:

```
std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), std::inserter(lut, lut.begin()), [&](const int i)
{
    return std::make_pair(i, ++index);
});
```

Он может быть заменён на более простой код, использующий `for`-петлю:

```
for(const int i : input)
{
    lut.emplace(i, ++index);
}
```

**Правка:**

Чтобы ваша функция `bubbleSort` заработала, должен существовать оператор `<` для сравнения структур `Bal`:

```
struct Bal{
unsigned short int Voltage;
unsigned short int index;
};

bool operator<(const Bal & lhs, const Bal & rhs)
{
    // Критерием является Voltage
    return lhs.Voltage < rhs.Voltage;
}
```

Comment: У меня qt 4.7.8 и данный код не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Отсортируйта массив индексов:

```
int input_data[]={11, 40, 35, 15, 25};
int index[]={0,1,2,3,4};
std::sort( std::begin( index), std::end(index), 
           [&input_data](int i, int j){ return  input_data[i] < input_data[j]; } );

std::cout<<" result : ";
for( int i : index )
    std::cout<<i<<", ";
std::cout<<std::endl;
```

Comment: И что мне это даст?